# my query is not picking up the created index

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I created an index named **user_type_index**

**My query:**

```
User.where("user_type IN (:user_types)", user_types: user_types)
user_types = ['super_admin', 'system_admin']
```

Even though `user_type` has an index, this query runs sequentially.

Tried dropping and creating the index, but still no use

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

def matching_with_user_types
   where("user_type IN (:user_types)", user_types: user_types)
end

end

user_types = ['super_admin', 'system_admin']
User.matching_with_user_types(user_types).explain
```

**Below is the output:**

```
Seq Scan on users  (cost=0.00..11.75 rows=2 width=537)
   Filter: ((user_type)::text = ANY ('{super_admin,system_admin}'::text[]))
(2 rows)
```

**Expected:** query using index
**Actual:** querying sequentially

**PostgreSQL query**

Fetching records matching with all

```
EXPLAIN SELECT id FROM "users" WHERE (user_type IN ('super_admin','system_admin','network','super')); 
QUERY PLAN 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
Seq Scan on users (cost=0.00..3039.28 rows=75228 width=377) 
  Filter: ((user_type)::text = ANY ('{'super_admin','system_admin','network','super'}'::text[])) 
(2 rows)
```

Fetching records matching with one:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT id FROM "users" WHERE (user_type IN ('super_admin')); 
QUERY PLAN 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
Seq Scan on users (cost=0.00..2789.24 rows=25418 width=377) 
  Filter: ((user_type)::text = ANY ('{'super_admin'}'::text[])) 
(2 rows)
```

Comment: For only two rows, the database will never use an index. And please show us the actual SQL query, not some Ruby code.

Comment: what is the minimum count required, to use the index @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: That really depends on the ratio between the total number of rows and the number of rows the query planner expects your where clause to return true for

Comment: added results of 2 different queries, which is still using sequential scan instead of indexed